# ui-sref is generating wrong url

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I'm working with **Angularjs with Nodejs** on a project. I'm using **UI-router** in my project for routing.
Here are configurations of the states in my app module file:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('booking', {
    url: '/user/booking',
    templateUrl: '/user/booking.html',
    resolve: {
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 300);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}).state('bookingDetails', {
    url: '/user/bookingDetails',
    templateUrl: '/user/bookingDetails.html',
    resolve: {
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 300);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}).state('notificationes', {
    url: '/user/notification',
    templateUrl: '/user/notification.html',
}).state('review', {
    url: '/user/review',
    templateUrl: '/user/review.html',
    resolve: {
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 300);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}).state('promo', {
    url: '/user/promoCode',
    templateUrl: '/user/promoCode.html'
}).state('setting', {
    url: '/user/setting',
    templateUrl: '/user/setting.html'
}).state('setting.personalInfo', {
    url: '/personalInfo',
    templateUrl: '/user/personalInfo.html',
   resolve: {
       delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
           var delay = $q.defer();
           $timeout(delay.resolve, 300);
           return delay.promise;
       }
   }
}).state('setting.changePassword', {
    url: '/changePassword',
    templateUrl: '/user/changePassword.html',
   resolve: {
       delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
           var delay = $q.defer();
           $timeout(delay.resolve, 300);
           return delay.promise;
       }
   }
}).state('setting.notificationPre', {
    url: '/notificationPreferences',
    templateUrl: '/user/notificationPreferences.html'
}).state('setting.changeAvatar', {
    url: '/changeAvatar',
    templateUrl: '/user/changeAvatar.html'
});
```

});

When I hitting the URL **"localhost:3000/user/booking"** then at the sidebar of the main page when I hover the sidebar tabs then it is showing the URLs like **"/user/user/booking", "/user/user/review"**.

you can see in the below screenshot.

[image]

Using ui-sref in the sidebar.html file

```
<li class="nav-item  " ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="review" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                <i class="icon-star"></i>
                <span class="title">Review</span>
            </a>

        </li>
```

I'm stuck into this, don't understand why it is repeating "/user". I tried a lot but couldn't found any solution to this issue. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prepend `/user` at the start of the url of every state you're defining.

Instead create an abstract state (for your example, name it `main` or whatever suites you) and give it the `/user` url and have all other user states extend it

e.g.

```
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    'abstract': true,
    url: '/user'
.state('main.booking', {
    url: '/booking',
    templateUrl: '/user/booking.html',
    resolve: {
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 300);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
})
.state('main.bookingDetails', {
    url: '/bookingDetails',
    templateUrl: '/user/bookingDetails.html',
    resolve: {
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 300);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
```

This way every state you redirect to will just take the local `url` value and append it to the `/user` defined in the abstract state.

Comment: I tried your solution. still it is creating "/user/user/booking" URL instead of "/user/booking".Can give me another solution?

Comment: why not just remove the `/user` prefix from the urls used in the user states ? (you're not doing that for the `settings` states)

Comment: i can't remove this because from the /user it is hit nodejs index.js file. I'm doing this in all the states including settings.